# page object: visit <page_url> in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

In `Geb` and `WATIR` there are certain keywords which we use to visit to the `page_url` which we have specified in page class. E.g. `to` keyword in `Geb` and `visit` keyword in `WATIR`.

What similar we can use in `nightwatch.js`. This is what I have tried but it gives error:

I have tried:

```
module.exports = {
    url: function () {
        return this.api.globals.launchUrl + "/goto/desiredPage.html";
    },
    commands: [pageCommands],
    elements: {}
};
```

In page class I am using it as:

```
desiredPage
          .url()   
          .foo()
          .bar();
client.end();
```

but it is giving error `.url is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the nightwatch examples inside the nightwatch folder for example:

```
[page-objects/home.js]
var searchCommands = {
  submit: function() {
    this.waitForElementVisible('@submitButton', 3000)
      .click('@submitButton')
      .api.pause(1000);
    return this; // Return page object for chaining
  }
};

module.exports = {
  url: 'http://google.com',
  commands: [searchCommands],
  elements: {
    searchBar: { selector: 'input[name=q]' },
    submitButton: { selector: 'button[type=submit]' }
  }
};
```

and then in the test:

```
/* jshint expr: true */
module.exports = {
  'Demo Google search test using page objects' : function (client) {
    var homePage = client.page.home();
    homePage.navigate();
    homePage.expect.element('@searchBar').to.be.enabled;

    homePage
      .setValue('@searchBar', 'Nightwatch.js')
      .submit();

    var resultsPage = client.page.searchResults();
    resultsPage.expect.element('@results').to.be.present.after(2000);
    resultsPage.expect.element('@results').to.contain.text('Nightwatch.js');
    resultsPage.expect.section('@menu').to.be.visible;

    var menuSection = resultsPage.section.menu;
    menuSection.expect.element('@web').to.be.visible;
    menuSection.expect.element('@video').to.be.visible;
    menuSection.expect.element('@images').to.be.visible;
    menuSection.expect.element('@shopping').to.be.visible;

    menuSection.productIsSelected('@web', function(result) {
      this.assert.ok(result, 'Web results are shown by default on search results page');
    });

    client.end();
  }
};
```

so "url()" command in pages does not exist you need to define the url in te page and the use "navigate()" instead.